# IN SQL Fifo deduct difference of stock from ageing report

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query but I am little bit confused how to deduct the difference stock from ageing

Here is my code

```
select *
from (
select *
,(  (a.total) - (s.TotalStock) ) diff 
from mak_stock_Ageing a
inner join [mak_stock_ageing _allstock]  s on s.itcode = a.Itcodeprd
where itcode = 15201
) a
```

Below is my table

| Itcodeprd | d30 | days31to60 | Above60 | total | itcode | TotalStock | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15201 | 100 | 53 | 170 | 323 | 15201 | 105 | 218 |

Expected:

| Itcodeprd | d30 | days31to60 | Above60 | total | TotalStock | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15201 | 100 | 5 | 0 | 323 | 105 | 218 |

I want to deduct the diff from above60 first when above60 is zero then from days31to60 when that is zero then frm d30

What should I do for this result please suggest

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible example? Such as a sample of the data and the expected output?

Comment: i have added the expected results

Comment: @MakhdoomLiaqat I think you need to describe more about your expected result.
Like how does `Above60` = 170 converting to `Above60` = 0, and `days31to60` = 53 converting to `days31to60` = 5?

Answer (score 0):

The Below i solved the answer

```
--create view mak_final_ageing_rpt as 
select *,
case when  (a.sold - a.Above60) > 0 then 0 else (Above60 - sold)    end ResultD60,
case when  (a.sold - a.Above60 ) > 0
then (

case when (a.sold - Above60 - a.days31to60)>0 then 0 else a.days31to60 - (sold - Above60) end  )
else
         a.days31to60 end result31to60,
case when (a.sold - a.Above60 -  a.days31to60) >0 then 
((a.Above60 + a.days31to60 + a.d30) - sold ) else a.d30 end resultd30

from (
select a.Itcodeprd,a.d30,a.days31to60,a.Above60,a.total,s.TotalStock
,(  (a.total) - (s.TotalStock) ) sold
from mak_stock_Ageing a
inner join [mak_stock_ageing _allstock]  s on s.itcode = a.Itcodeprd
where itcode = 15201 or itcode = 8438 or itcode = 12887 or itcode = 15516
) a
```